# MvvmCross MvxWindowsPage<TViewModel> compilation error

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, mvvmcross

I am writing a `Xamarin.iOS`, `Xamarin.Android` and `UWP` cross-platform application with the MvvmCross framework.

I am making a LoginPage which has a LoginViewModel. In the `Xamarin.iOS`, `Xamarin.Android` projects, the binding of the ViewModel and the View with below works just fine

```
public class LoginActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<LoginViewModel>
```

```
public partial class LoginViewController : MvxViewController<LoginViewModel>
```

Trying to do the same as above on `UWP` project, I get some error.

In XAML:

```
<views:MvxWindowsPage
x:TypeArguments="viewModels:LoginViewModel" x:Class="MyApp.UWP.Views.LoginView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="using:MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views"
xmlns:viewModels="using:MyApp.PresentationCore.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d">
```

And my C# code is

```
public sealed partial class LoginView : MvxWindowsPage<LoginViewModel>
```

But I get compilation errors. How can I resolve them?

> - `Unknown member 'TypeArguments' on element 'MvxWindowsPage'
> - The name "LoginViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "using:MyApp.PresentationCore.ViewModels".
> - GenericArguments[0], 'System.Object', on 'MvvmCross.WindowsUWP.Views.MvxWindowsPage`1[TViewModel]' violates the
>     constraint of type 'TViewModel'.

I think the errors are a little ambiguous because at the first error there is no templated version, but the third error is about a template constraint violation.

I know there is an option binding the ViewModel and the View with naming convention or attributes, but I would like to use this strongly typed solution.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I created a basic demo starting from the MvvmCross solution teamplate. You can access it [here](https://github.com/cviktor/MvvmCrossExample) The only thing I changed is the base class of the FirstView in the UWP project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I believe UWP does not support `TypeArguments` and subsequently generic types parameters for a base pages. You can check out the [Prism GitHub thread](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/58#issuecomment-135793131) where they discuss it. So you will have to go with one of the other registration options.

---

Mvvmcross offers various alternative approaches for registering your `View` to a `ViewModel`. During initialisation of Mvvmcross it will attempt to register your `ViewModel` to your `View` using [`MvxViewModelViewTypeFinder`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Core/Core/ViewModels/MvxViewModelViewTypeFinder.cs#L31) in the following order:

***Attribute based registration:***

You can add `MvxViewFor` attribute to your page class.

```
[MvxViewFor(typeof(FirstViewModel))]
public sealed partial class FirstView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public FirstView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

***Concrete type based registration:***

You can register your `View` to your `ViewModel` by specifying the concrete type of the ViewModel.

```
public sealed partial class FirstView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public new FirstViewModel ViewModel => base.ViewModel as FirstViewModel;

    public FirstView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Or in the case of Android and iOS where generic base class can be used:

```
// Android
public class FirstActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity<FirstViewModel>

// iOS
public class FirstViewController : MvxViewController<FirstViewModel>
```

***Convention based registration:***

You can have your view and ViewModel follow the same naming convention and Mvvmcross will map them for you (xxxView and xxxViewModel)

*View*

```
public sealed partial class FirstView : MvxWindowsPage
{
    public FirstView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

*ViewModel*

```
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
```